# When should one answer their own question rather than build on what is already there?

Tags: discussion, editing, accepted-answer

Let me put this forward with an example...

I was stuck on an SSH issue on my Ubuntu server. I then got a few comments from one user and an answer from another.

I thought that the answer gave me directions in solving the problem, but was incomplete. And once I figured it out, I thought the best thing would be to complete it. So I edited the answer, then accepted it. After all, I appreciate what these two users did I thought they deserved credit for their efforts.

But I was advised to give my own answer. So I did.

So what's the right thing to do here? Do I go with my own answer and accept it, or do I edit the answer of someone else and accept that?

Comment: Is it about [this suggested edit](http://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/75458)? I rejected it for the reason you can see in the link. Others seem to disagree with me on this, though. But even the answerer [disagrees](http://askubuntu.com/questions/246930/ubuntu-server-ssh-is-showing-in-process-but-does-not-work#comment307071_246948), so, I think we can make this a very simple discussion. :)

Comment: @gertvdijk WOW! I did not even mention a name but you traced me to this post ;) ... Actually, while I appreciate all the answers that I get, I try to give credit to whoever possible for their support. So adding to an answer seemd logical to me. Yes, this was concerning you and neo. I couldn't add to yours since you had only comments. So I added to neo's... I think Jorge Castro is suggesting the same. I'm only trying to justify my stance in maintaining an existing answer. Perhaps you're correct as well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually try to improve an answer first, either by adding links to references or other questions on the site or generally improving it.

However if it ends up that I'm making so many changes that I'm butchering the person's answer I'll just post my own. If someone's post really helped me but didn't quite meet my needs and I post my own I make sure I give them proper credit ([example](https://askubuntu.com/a/4578/235)) so that the question now has a complete solution, but also other information that might be useful to the next person with the problem.

It's really a judgement call on your part.

Comment: Ultimately accepting an answer after having edited it still gives the answerer credit. And at the same time it helps others (and definetly helps me when I need to refer to it in the future). But I get your point. Thanks!